# deployement of the Laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I deployed my Laravel site on Hostinger and made the necessary changes in the index.php file.  but this error is returned, I don't understand  include(/home/u480503497/domains/qavaainnovate.com/laravelblog/vendor/composer/../spatie/laravel-ignition/src/Http/Controllers/UpdateConfigController.php): : Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
the indexed error is in the index.php
at line 52
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBVT3.png)

to deploy my site on hostinger, I created a folder laravelblog which contains all my files except the public
[my hostinger domain and the files it contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJhi.png)
then I modified the paths in the index.php

Comment: try this if it work then I willl tell you what to do next
'"yourHostURL"/your_project_name/public'

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: cab you share link to your project/domain means "https//yourDomain_name/and_project_path/ETC"?